# Set the styling of an element when you click on an href link using inLine styling and CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I apologize in advance to all who might question this question. I have searched and tried many different solutions, before finally trying to perhaps "hack" it.

And I know there must be many other methods to use (JQuery, JavaScript etc.), but I am not sure how to solve this issue other than using CSS.

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**
I am experiencing a situation in Angular where when I click on one of the anchor menu links, my main content view moves about `30px` left. And I don't know why!

I have checked my CSS, I have checked for `!important` rules, I have checked inLine styling, and everything else I can think of.

When I look at my Styles in Chrome dev tools, my CSS is correct for my `#main` element:

```
#main {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 199px);
    margin-left: 199px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

And even after I have clicked and the `#main` element moved `30px` left, the styling in the Chrome dev tools shows no change.

And when I delete the `199px` of my margin-left parameter in the dev tools, and change it back to 199px, the element re positions itself in the perfect position...

**So, I had the following ideas;**

1. Create a CSS hover rule on the href links that resizes the `#main` element, or
2. Create an inLine rule on my href links that will resize the `#main` element.

This is what my href links look like:

```
<li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('mentionList', $event)"><img title="Mentions List" src="images/postList.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Mentions List</span></a></li>
```

This is my CSS for the #main element, and my menu:

```
.adminMenu {
    background: #3a3a3a;
    padding: 24px 0 0;
    color: #eadfdb;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    left: 0;
    width: 199px
}

.side-nav li a {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eadfdb;
    transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    color: #eadfdb;
    height: 27px;
    overflow: hidden
}

.side-nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #f37934
}


#main {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 199px);
    margin-left: 199px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out
}
```

Here is my menu to see the classes:

```
<section class="adminMenu" ng-class="menuStateClass">
  <h3>{{fusionTitle}}</h3>
  <div id="minMaxMenu" ng-click="minMaxMenu()">
    <img src="images/collapse.svg" title="Click to expand" width="23" height="23" id="menuExpand" class="collapseIcon" ng-class="arrowDirectionClass" /> <span ng-show="showMenuHideText">Hide Menu</span>
  </div>
  <nav class="side-nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="socialMediaClick"><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('top', $event)"><img title="Post List" src="images/postList.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Summary</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('mentionList', $event)"><img title="Mentions List" src="images/postList.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Mentions List</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('volume', $event)"><img title="Volume" src="images/volumeHour.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Volume</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('mediaSource', $event)"><img title="Media Source" src="images/postSource.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Media Source</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('sentiment', $event)"><img title="Sentiment" src="images/sentiment.svg" height="25" /><span class="navText">Sentiment</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('engagers', $event)"><img title="Engagers" src="images/engagement.svg" height="25" /><span class="navText">Engagers</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('linkShares', $event)"><img title="Link Shares" src="images/source_list.svg" height="25" /><span class="navText">Link Shares</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('hashtags', $event)"><img title="Hashtags" src="images/hashtag.svg" height="25" /><span class="navText">Hashtags</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('appsUsed', $event)"><img title="Apps Used" src="images/twitterPlatform.svg" height="25" /><span class="navText">Apps Used</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('demographics', $event)"><img title="Demographics" src="images/demographics.svg" height="25" /><span class="navText">Demographics</span></a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('wordCloud', $event)"><img title="Word Cloud" src="images/wordCloud.svg" height="25" /><span class="navText">Word Cloud</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#summary_social_mentions_social_media#/support"><img title="Support" src="images/help.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Support</span></a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide us with the page's link?

Comment: i think you should not used calc since it is used for calculating the gap between right n left margin of the content. Try to remove that line

Comment: @Yahya H Hussein The site and app has subscription and security, and I am not allowed to share it. Thank you, though!

Comment: @digit Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it, but it made no difference. :(

Comment: Hmm. There must be something that triggering the main content shifting to the left.

Comment: Anyway, there is alternative solution for this. Avoid using margin to calculate width of menu and main content because if you want to target multiple platform such as desktop and mobile it will not calculate properly. Try to use float left and right only and set width for menu 20%, main 80%

Comment: @digit Good idea. I will give it bash. Interestingly; I noticed it only happens  in `IE` that it shifts beyond the margin. In `Firefox` it shifts to the menu (doesn't overlap), and in `Chrome` it works perfectly. Yet another `IE` incompatibility issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If anyone else might have a similar issue, I fixed mine using the following solution in JavaScript:**

```
 $scope.redirectTodiv = function (divname, event) {
                var id = $location.hash();
                $location.hash(divname);
                $anchorScroll();
                $location.hash(id);

                styleAdjust();

};

function styleAdjust() {

    //DETECT BROWSER

    // Opera 8.0+
    var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

    // Firefox 1.0+
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

    // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
    var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0 || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);

    // Internet Explorer 6-11
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

    // Edge 20+
    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

    // Chrome 1+
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // GET STYLE

    var elementMargin = document.getElementById("main");
    var style = elementMargin.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(elementMargin);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ADJUST

    if (isIE) {

        var oldValue = parseInt(style.marginLeft, 10);
        console.log("Current marginLeft: " + oldValue);

        var newValue = oldValue + 40;
        console.log("New marginLeft: " + newValue);

        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = newValue + "px";

    }
    else if (isFirefox) {

        var oldValue = parseInt(style.marginLeft, 10);
        console.log("Current marginLeft: " + oldValue);

        var newValue = oldValue + 20;
        console.log("New marginLeft: " + newValue);

        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = newValue + "px";
    }
}
```